# I get this error each time I try to run rosmake --> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I created a new package and try to run rosmake...However, each time I do that this error appears and dunno why!

The error:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Thanks
George

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12292/i-get-this-error-each-time-i-try-to-run-rosmake---%3E-runtimeerror:-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-cmp/) by [giorgosera](https://answers.ros.org/users/1375/giorgosera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error can occur when you have cyclical dependencies. Does your package depend on a package that also depends on your package? Sorry for the confusing wording, but I don't know of a better way to say it.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of a cyclical dependency:

Package A is called `my_robot_config`. Package B is called `my_robot_sensors`.

In the manifest.xml files:

```
my_robot_config

<depend package="my_robot_sensors" />
```

---

```
my_robot_sensors

<depend package="my_robot_config" />
```

All you have to do is look through the manifest.xml files in your packages to make sure that two packages don't depend on one another.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-09**:
I'd just look at the two manifest and see if one is listed in the other

**Comment by [giorgosera](https://answers.ros.org/users/1375/giorgosera/) on 2011-12-09**:
Is there a way I can check which dependency actually cause the cycle?